# Is it possible to use an output name created within RMD chunk as knit file destination?

Tags: batch-file, r-markdown, knitr

I am knitting markdown code initiated from a database command button with a shell command to execute a batch file. The goal here is to knit the file into a directory specific to the database record. Batch file execution currently looks like this:

```
"Rscript.exe" -e "library('knitr'); rmarkdown::render('MyCode.Rmd', output_file="MyRMD.html")"
```

Inside the rmd file I create a variable (say 'out_dir') that contains the directory string where I want the output file to be stored. Is there any way I can use this variable to direct where knitr will store the rendered file? Other than YAML parameters, can you control knitr output options from within the code?

Comment: Are you sure that your question is related to a __Windows batch__ script file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` processed by the __Windows Command Processor__ `cmd.exe` and not a Linux/Mac __shell__ script file with file extension `.sh` interpreted by the shell script interpreter `bash`? The posted command line looks like a shell script command line and not a Windows batch script command line.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the approach I was trying to accomplish, but the workaround was to build a front end script to the markdown document that did the necessary pre-processing and then passed the values using "output_file", "output_dir" and a "params()" list  matching the YAML header in the rmd (Note this part is not necessary in solving the original question, but since I took this approach it makes it handy to pull even more pre-processing code out of the rmd and into the front end passing values through params). So the front end initiates the knit:

```
rmarkdown::render("MyCode.Rmd", 
              params = list(P1 = p1, P2 = p2),
              output_file = 'MyRMD.html',
              output_dir = 'Dir_From_Database_Record')
```

And just for completeness the markdown rmd YAML header from MyCode.RMD looks like:

```
output: html_document
params:
  P1: NA
  P2: NA
```